What is the distribution of the unbiased estimator of variance for normally distributed variables?
I must be making some mistake in my derivation of the distribution of the unbiased variance estimator for i.i.d. $X_{i} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right)$.
We have $\bar{X} =\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}$.
Therefore, $\bar{X} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}\right)$ and $X_{i}-\bar{X}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{n+1}{n}\sigma^2\right)$.
Hence, $X_{i}-\bar{X} = \sigma\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}} Z_{i}$ where $Z_{i}\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
\hat{\sigma}&=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2} \\
&=\sigma\frac{n+1}{n\left(n-1\right)}\sum^{n}_{i=1}Z_{i}^{2} \\
&= \sigma^{2}\frac{n+1}{n\left(n-1\right)}Q
\end{align}$$
where $Q \sim \chi^{2} \left(n\right)$
However, clearly this implies the estimator is biased.
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\sigma}\right]=\frac{n+1}{n-1}\sigma^{2}$$
Where did I go wrong?

$X_i$ and $\bar X$ are not independent so your $X_{i}-\bar{X}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{n+1}{n}\sigma^2\right)$ is not correct.

@Henry Right, I missed that. If you could provide the correct derivation, I’d accept your answer!

I'm quite that there are correct derivations already on site. Try a few searches

Not only are $X_i$ and $\overline X$ not independent, but the terms in the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2$ are not independent of each other. Notice that the terms $X_i-\overline X$ necessarily sum to zero, so they must be negatively correlated with each other. Can you tell me how much acquaintance you have with linear algebra and the geometry of orthogonal projections, and with the spherically symmetric nature of the normal distribution with variance $I_n. \qquad$

Well, apparently this question was off-topic? Anyways, @MichaelHardy I’m interested in learning what you have to say. I suppose one could break up the sum of $\bar{X}$ and combine it with the $X_{i}$ term. That seems to resolve the issue.

@YEpd : I don't know why this was closed as "off-topic".

I have voted to reopen this. The reason for closing it says "those that demand a solution need to indicate clearly at what step help or advice are needed", but it appears to me that the question does indicate at what steps help is needed.

@YEpd : There is a reason why I asked about the degree of your familiarity with geometry and linear algebra. But you haven't answered that.

As pointed out in the comments, I made a mistake in assuming that $X_{i}$ and $\bar{X}$ are independent.
For i.i.d. $X_{i}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right)$, a correct derivation would be as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{\sigma}&=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}X_{r}\right)^{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}X_{i}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r\neq i}X_{r}\right)^{2}\\
\end{aligned}$$
Now, $\frac{n-1}{n}X_{i}$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r\neq i}X_{r}$ are indeed independent. So, we have $\frac{n-1}{n}X_{i}-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r\neq i}X_{r} =\sigma\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}Z_{i}$ where $Z_{i}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$. Hence,
$$\begin{align}
\hat{\sigma}&=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sigma\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}Z_{i}\right)^{2}\\
&=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_{i}^{2}\\
&=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}Q
\end{align}$$ where $Q\sim\chi^{2}\left(n\right)$.
As expected, we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\sigma}\right]=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[Q\right]=\sigma^{2}$$
